# "5 was not expected at this time"

Tags: batch-file

So, me and a friend are making a Batch RPG, and we have the battle system based on a random number b/w 1 & 10. The code snippet is:

```
SET /A RANval=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
echo %RANval%
pause
if %RANval% GTR 5 goto O_Battle
if %RANval% LSS 5 goto O_NoBattle
if %RANval% == 5 goto O_RareBattle
```

but the issue is: it keeps crashing with "5 was unexpected at this time"
Could someone help me with this?

EDIT: The issue appears to chancge wheh i change the 5 under LSS 5 AND GTR 5. i.e. if i made it "LSS 3" and "GTR 3" it says "3 was unexpected at this time"
(Sorry, this is my first time on stackoverflow)

Comment: Might want to consider using a proper programming environment .. it'll make life easier.

Comment: Which Win version? This works fine on Win7.

Comment: makes for better work stories when years later he can say,"Dude, that's nothing, I wrote an RPG in a batch file" @user2864740

Comment: Is this code inside a for loop?

Comment: No, but it IS inside a "lf loc == this (   )"

Answer (score 0):

If I put the following in a batch file, it works for me,  so maybe there's something wrong with your goto labels?

```
SET /A RANval=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
echo %RANval%

if %RANval% GTR 5 goto O_Battle
if %RANval% LSS 5 goto O_NoBattle
if %RANval% == 5 goto O_RareBattle


:O_Battle
echo "Battle"
goto end
:O_NoBattle
echo "No Battle"
goto end
:O_RareBattle
echo "Rare"
goto end

:end
```

Comment: do you know what line its failing on?

Comment: if I change the "LSS #" statement AND the "GTR #" statement, it changes to "# was unexpected at this time" (replace # with any number)

Comment: interesting...hold on, let me try again... I'll edit this comment with my results     EDIT: Nope, still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Alrighty, I'll check in the morning, ill update this later. Im going to sleep

Answer (score 0):

The error message `5 was unexpected at this time` is exactly what you'll see under Windows (XP and 7, at least) if you type:

```
if GTR 5 echo blah
```

That leads me to believe that your variable names in the `if` statements are incorrect since something like:

```
if %no_such_var% GTR 5 echo blah
```

would result in a the variable being replaced with nothing <sup>(a)</sup> and that error occurring.

So check that you haven't done something silly like using `1` (wun) instead of `l` (ell) in your `if` statements. If need be, use a simpler variable that's hard to get wrong, such as `r` :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Interestingly enough, this only seems to happen within batch files, not from the command line. It may be there are different rules for the two but, if you're testing, ensure you do it in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

(This is LufiaGuy2000, it won't let me use the G+ login on my school computer >:(  )
I fixed it, I just had to remove the parentheses around the code. I guess I'll have to work around not using parentheses. unless someone else comes up with a solution to that. Thank you guys for your answers! :)

Comment: Please show the code for your answer for future users. It is also not advisable to have two logins, especially where one profile is answering a question posed by the other. Glad it worked out in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Because you had it inside `()`, you will need to use delayed expansion.

To use delayed expansion use `!` instead of `%` for your variables.

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

IF "A"=="A" (
  SET /A RANval=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
  echo !RANval!
  pause
  if !RANval! GTR 5 goto O_Battle
  if !RANval! LSS 5 goto O_NoBattle
  if !RANval! == 5 goto O_RareBattle
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using delayed expansion. At the start of your batch file, put:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
```

Also, surround your variables with `!` instead of `%`, like this:

```
if !RANval! GTR 5 goto O_Battle
if !RANval! LSS 5 goto O_NoBattle
if !RANval! == 5 goto O_RareBattle
```

This should solve the problem.